# EXTJS 5.1 Matching json values for log in screen

Tags: json, extjs5

I have built a controller for my login screen:

```
    Ext.define('ies.view.login.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.login',
    onLoginClick: function(){

        //get form field values
        var username = this.lookupReference('username').getValue();
        var password = this.lookupReference('password').getValue();
        var LoginError = document.getElementById("displayfield-1014-inputEl");
        //console.log(username + ' ' + password);



// set usernames and a single passwords
if ((username === 'carol' || username === 'denise' || username === 'coley' || username === 'yegappan' || username === 'julie' || username === 'dawn' || username === 'yvonne' || username === 'chuck' || username === 'belinda' || username === 'atlante' || username === 'blake' || username === 'ernie' || username === 'Patrick.Dwyer') && password === 'password1'){

        // Set the localStorage value to true
        localStorage.setItem("TutorialLoggedIn", true);
        localStorage.setItem(username, true);
        //console.log("Authenticated");

        // Remove Login Window
        this.getView().destroy();

        // Add the main view to the viewport
        Ext.widget('app-main');
    } else {


        LoginError.innerHTML = "Wrong Username or Password";
        LoginError.style.color = "#ff0000";
        console.log("Not authenticated");
    }
    }
});
```

This works great, but I'm trying to get the values for authentication from a json file:

```
[
    {
        "username":"angel",
        "password":"password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"chuck",
        "password":"password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"yvonne",
        "password":"password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"belinda",
        "password":"password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"patrick",
        "password":"password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"carol",
        "password":"password1"
    }
]
```

The following code gets the ajax request and gives an alert to display the username. I'm getting it to work but I get undefined as the username:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'app/model/cred.json',
  params: {
    someParam: 'someValue'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(result, request) {
    var json = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
    Ext.Msg.alert('JSON Data', 'Username is: ' + json.username);       
  },
  failure: function(result, request) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'An Error has bitten ye squarely on the keister...');
  } 
});
```

I guess the question is how do I get the values of the json file and if the username and password matches, set the local storage which allows the user to log in to the app... I'm stuck with how to approach this--I can't even get the values of the json file to display in the alert...

Here's a fiddle with just the ajax request: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ift

All help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is look at `var json` value. Change your callback code to below and you will see `username` value in message box.

`Ext.Msg.alert('JSON Data', 'Username is: ' + json[0].username);`

Comment: Hi DevPat, this really helped me out. Can you provide your feedback on this code? I can't seem to get the view to be removed. Not sure what's happening with this code here: `this.getView().destroy();`. I have this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ig6. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It works, but I have to refresh the page to destroy the current view... Can't figure out how to get that done or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @AtlanteAvila please provide complete code in your latest sencha fiddle link.

Comment: Got it to work! I needed to define this in `this.getView..`. "this" was referring to the ajaxrequest and needed it to work with the onloginclick function. I added defined this in the onloginclick function with: `var me = this;` and then replaced the `this.getView().destroy();` with `me.getView().destroy();` and it worked! Thanks again for your help this was great!